# liquibase not updating new data in database for spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have an existing PostgreSQL database having 5 roles in role table added via liquibase load data csv file, now i want to add a new role in role table using liquibase. How is this done in liquibase with Maven?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new change set with a new unique id and add new csv file with new data.
eg in ur csv

> `id;role  newid;newrole`

```
   <changeSet id="UniqueId" author="author">
     <loadData tableName="role"
              file="your.csv"
              separator=";">
    </loadData>

    </changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new `changeset` xml, something like this -

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="insert-example">
    <insert catalogName="cat"
        dbms="h2, oracle"
        schemaName="public"
        tableName="person">
    <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

You can refer to [this](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/insert.html) for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i need insert new data only